# How to double for loop over two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have dataframe consisting of unknown places, just a set of latitude and longitudes. This list contains of a lot of places that almost have the same coordinates. I want to create a new dataframe with 'filtered unknown places', where places that are almost the same are merged into one place. For each 'filtered unknown place' we keep track of a counter indicating the number of unknown places it contains.

I tried to solve this with two for loops; first looping over the unknown places and within that for loop looping over the filtered unknown places, see below.

```
accuracy = 0.2 #km
df_unknown_places_filtered = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['GpsLatitude', 'GpsLongitude', 'Count'])
        
for i, row in df_unknown_places.iterrows():
    min_dist = 999999
    closest = 0
    for j, row2 in df_unknown_places_filtered.iterrows():
        dist = self.distance(row['GpsLatitude'], row['GpsLongitude'], row2['GpsLatitude'], row2['GpsLongitude'])
        if dist < min_dist:
            min_dist = dist
            closest = j
    if min_dist < accuracy:
        current_count = df_unknown_places_filtered.at[closest, 'Count'] 
        df_unknown_places_filtered.at[closest,'Count'] = current_count + 1
    else:
        row_to_insert = {'GpsLatitude':row['GpsLatitude'],
                        'GpsLongitude':row['GpsLongitude'],
                        'Count': 1                                                           
                                            }
        df_unknown_places_filtered = pd.concat([df_unknown_places_filtered, pd.DataFrame.from_records([row_to_insert])], axis = 0)
```

It seems however that for the second iterrows the value of j is not updating and I have no idea why. Anyone an idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your df_unknown_places_filtered has no rows.

Comment: Thanks! Turned out be something different. df_unknown_places_filtered got rows, added i n the concat function. However, the problem was in the function. ignore_index = True was missing, giving all the rows index 0.